# Белые и желтые цифры в блоке кода

Tags: обсуждение, подсветка-синтаксиса, блок-кода

В связи с чем возникает такой эффект, что некоторые цифры в блоке кода желтые, а некоторые белые?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос возник из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1300125/3) топика

Comment: у меня 1-го эти цифры не жёлтые, а оранжевые?

Comment: @return orange is the new yellow!

Comment: @return видимо особенности монитора, у меня они все таки более желтые, чем оранжевые :)

Comment: Всегда можно сделать скриншот и проверить цвет пикселя в подходящем редакторе.

Comment: Orange letter matter!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Подсветка обеспечивается сторонним софтом [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js). Язык подсветки выбирается на основании упомянутых в вопросе меток. В данном случае автоматически выбирается подсветка для python. Однако отформатированный текст - это не питонячий код, поэтому стоило бы указывать язык форматирования явно, а не полагаться на метку из вопроса.

Я позволил себе смелость добавить `lang-none` к блокам кода и ожидаемо подсветка (кривая в том числе) исчезла.

Answer (score 4):

При отображении `pandas` датафрейма из `python` в блоке кода, получилось добиться стабильного отображения при добавлении тега `lang-c#`

````
```lang-c#
````

Без тегов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С тегом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]